# The modal close icon and the text of the modal are incorrect

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

```html
<div class="modal-title-area">
  <div class="modal-name">
    @{ ViewBag.Title = "Kişisel Bilgiler"; } @EmployeeCardRes.PersonalInfo
  </div>
  <div class="modal-root-page tag-label">
    <i class="close icon"></i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-divider"></div>
<div class="modal-content-area">
  <div class="two-fields">
    <div class="field ">
      <div class="label">
        @EmployeeCardRes.FirstName @EmployeeCardRes.LastName
        <div class="text">@Model.FirstName @Model.LastName</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <div class="label">@EmployeeCardRes.PositionCode
        <div class="text">@ViewBag.Position</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Labels inside div need to correspond to posts. but the label is going down the text above how can I fix it.

[image]
I want to do like that

Comment: Do you have any javascript you can show on how you are trying to close the modal?

Comment: StackOverflow guidelines stat that you should at least make an attempt at solving the problem. This isn't a forum to complete work for you, only to assist when you hit specific issues that you can't solve yourself.

Comment: That wasn't the main issue you were stuck with, I just asked. The main issue is that the articles are coming together.

Comment: What do you mean by 'coming together'? Do you mean that each line of text is too close to one another?

Comment: I mean Ad Soyad Albert Einstein then should be go down

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't understand what you want. 'then should be go down' really isn't clear what you want. Might I suggest you add an image of a) what you want and b) what you have now to your question? I think that would be the best idea

Comment: The one in the first picture is shown but I want to do it like in the second picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to split out your div elements for label and text for each row, so where you have

```
<div class="field">
  <div class="label">@EmployeeCardRes.PositionCode
    <div class="text">@ViewBag.Position</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You should replace it with something more like this:

```
<div class="field">
  <div class="label">
    @EmployeeCardRes.PositionCode
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    @ViewBag.Position
  </div>
</div>
```

You can then use CSS to modify the way the DOM positions and displays them, something like the following will give you bold text and a little separation:

```
.label,
.text {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 5px;
  min-width: 200px;
}
```